# python sed not working

Tags: python, regex, sed, python-2.4

Why is it so hard to do sed like operation in Python?

```
cat temp$$ | sed '/ENTRY/d' | sed '/VERSION/d' > temp$$1
```

The following attempt simply doesn't work (instead of writing to file I'm printing to screen):

```
 70 for line in open("temp5027", 'r'):
 71     
 72     if re.search("ENTRY|VERSION", line) != None:
 73         pass
 74     else:
 75         print line
```

A frustrated first time python user.

Note: I'm using python 2.4 so no "with" support yet.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Is it intentional that you are printing those lines again that do not match (for which re.search returned `None)`?

Comment: Yes. it's intentional. I'm using the regex as a filter.

Comment: That's why I pass when the filter applies. Sort of as removal from screen. Idea is that I can write to screen is easier for debug.

Comment: But your write `line` both at line 71 *and* on line 75. This writes the line *twice*. `sed` doesn't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Write to file with Python 2.4**

```
import re

i = open("in.txt")
o = open("out.txt", "w")

for line in i:
    if re.search("ENTRY|VERSION", line):
       o.write(line)

o.close()
i.close()
```

**Write to file with modern Python**

```
import re

with open("in.txt") as i, open("out.txt", "w") as o:
    for line in i:
        if re.search("ENTRY|VERSION", line):
           o.write(line)
```

**Bonus**

Improve your `sed` usage.

```
$ sed -e '/ENTRY/d' -e '/VERSION/d' < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Oops forgot to mention I'm using a 2.4 version on server..no "with"